# Jekyll: How can I access `_posts` from html located in subfolders?

Tags: jekyll

```
=> tree

....
├── 404.html
├── index.html
├── about.md
├── _config.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── _includes
├── _layouts
├── _pages
│   ├── ai.html
│   └── quant.html 
├── _posts
│   ├── 2017-01-09-daummovie-rxjs.md
│   ├── 2017-01-12-kage.md
│   ├── 2017-01-25-nomad.md
...
```

**_pages/quant.html**

```
---
layout: board
permalink: /quant/
---
<ul id="post-list">
    {% for post in paginator.posts %}
        {% include item.html %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% include pagination.html %}
```

**item.html**

```
<li class="post-item post {{ post.post_class }}">
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">
        <h3 class="post-title">{{ post.title }} &nbsp;<post class="post-date"> ({{ post.date | date: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' }})</post></h3>

        <p class="post-excerpt">{{ post.excerpt | strip_html | truncatewords: 75 }}</p>
    </a>
    <p class="post-tags">
        {% for tag in post.tags %}
            <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/tags/{{ tag }}" title="{{ tag }}"
               class="tag tag-{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>

    <!--<div class="clearfix"></div>-->
</li>
```

I'd like to access posts in `_posts` directory from `quant.html` which located inside `_pages`.

When I put quant.html out of _pages it works but when I put that file inside _pages it doesn't work..... I think that if I put `html` file inside subfolder, it can not recognize `paginator`..

Above code of `quant.html` doesn't show any posts.

How can I get all posts?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the question is not making much sense. Please refactor it. I think you either want to send the current post from the for loop to the include or simply list the post title (or something like that). At the moment, your for loop is not doing anything except for outputting whatever the item.html include file has inside it. I'm assuming your include file needs the post object to do something with it. Right?

If so, you will need to send the `post` to the include and then retrieve it from the item.html `include`.

To send the `post` to the `item.html`:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  {% include item.html item = post %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then, to get the `post` for use in `item.html`:

```
# _include/item.html

<p>This is the post: {{ include.item }}</p>
```

Comment: I think you didn't catch my point (or my post is not that obvious)... When I put `quant.html` out of `_pages` it works but when I put that file inside `_pages` it doesn't work..... I think that if I put `html` file inside subfolder, it can not recognize `paginator` ...

Comment: I added `item.html` so check it out too!

Comment: `item.html` does not know what the `post` variable is! :) You have to send the `post` variable to it as per my answer.

Comment: I got why it doesn't work:  https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination ("Don't set a permalink! Setting a permalink in the front matter of your blog page will cause pagination to break. Just omit the permalink")

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please mark the question as answered if it works.

Comment: As the docs state, you cannot declare a permalink on a post's front-matter when using the default paginator. Either remove the permalink or the paginator. You can use other community plugins for pagination or create your own with a different rendering sequence. Can you include a couple of posts' front-matter please so I can test it more specifically against your setup.